# Wordpress - Divi - javascript - cache

Tags: javascript, wordpress, caching

I have custom JavaScript files in `theme\divi\js`. I modify these files and upload them to a GoDaddy web server, but the old version of these files keeps loading.

I clear browser cache, disable cache, clear localStorage... I've even called GoDaddy tech support to disable CDN cache, but it is still loading the old files until the next day (I've discovered the refreshing pattern… but I'm still not sure about it). I even turned off the WordPress Super Cache.

Please let me know if you have experience on this matter. Why are the JavaScript files not able to load instantly, and how can I control this?

Comment: I would recommend that you post this question with the [Wordpress Development Stack Exchange Forum](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much!  I ll do it now.

Comment: Hi @AnhN. I'm an engineer at GoDaddy. Not sure what hosting product you are using, but if you share your domain name I'm happy to help make sure things get flushed and you get this working the way you want.

Comment: Breeze is a cache plugin that offers the most complete set of functionality for all your WordPress cache management requirements. At the time of this email, it has 20,000+ active installs and the number is rising rapidly. It provides all industry-standard functionalities, completely FOR FREE.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/breeze/